# Why A20 line is on a keyboard controller

Tags: assembly, operating-system

I make a small search on google. But i didnt find anything about why, everything is about how to enable it. My question is, why A20 line is on a keyboard controller?

Comment: Because the keyboard controller had a spare pin?

Comment: I get it. I am pretty sure they werent going to use this pin for this job :)

Comment: @YahyaGedik Any other solution would have required additional components. Putting the A20 line on the keyboard controller only required a trace and a nand gate (which is needed anyway).

Comment: See also [osdev article](http://wiki.osdev.org/A20_Line)

Comment: Thanks for article. I think i should mark this question as marked now. * i mean solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [simple google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=a20%20line%20keyboad%20controller&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ckIYWcOjIoqp8wel0LS4Aw) would have answered your question.

The [top result](http://wiki.osdev.org/A20_Line) in google says:

> The traditional method for A20 line enabling is to directly probe the keyboard controller. The reason for this is that Intel's [8042 keyboard controller](http://wiki.osdev.org/%228042%22_PS/2_Controller) had a spare pin which they decided to route the A20 line through. This seems foolish now given their unrelated nature, but at the time computers weren't quite so standardized. Keyboard controllers are usually derivatives of the 8042 chip. By programming that chip accurately, you can either enable or disable bit #20 on the address bus.
>
> When your PC boots, the A20 gate is always disabled, but some BIOSes do enable it for you, as do some high-memory managers (HIMEM.SYS) or bootloaders (GRUB).

basically the answer is the 8042 had some spare capacity and engineers used that as a quick and cheap hack. Also every computer must have a keyboard so they assumed it must always have a keyboard controller.

Note that modern CPU's (post Haswell) always have A20 **enabled** and do not support disabling it.
This of course makes sense in a 64-bit era. The fact that this breaks 1970's broken software is perhaps a good thing.

Comment: Are you sure that A20 is always enabled? Most of the operating system development tutorials put a section about how to enable A20. Perhaps working on a virtual machine? And why downvote?

Comment: On modern CPU's A20 is always enabled.  Post Haswell which started selling in 2014. No wonder OS tutorials don't take this into account yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think my cpu does not have A20 enabled always. Its a Amd Fx4100. Is there any decent articles/books for operating system development?